# The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to build an app that contains chat, but the error message appears:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

My firebase rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
match /users/{uid}{
allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
}

match /users/{uid}{
allow read: if request.auth != null;
}

match /chat/{document=**}{
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS4Bv.png)

as seen in the picture above, when I write a message and send it, it doesn't appear in the screen, and the error message is written in terminal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make your rule as per below. It is also secure

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you teach me how to execute your command?

Comment: @DevConductor Go to console.firebase.com > Firestore Database > Rules. Then copy paste given code and click on Publish button.

Answer (score 1):

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, 
      write: if true;
     }
  }
}
```

This can be used when there is no need for authentication access.

Comment: Why use this over the other solution? Wouldn't it be better to not unconditionally allow write access to something?

Comment: this can be used when there is no need for authentication access.

Comment: That's good information to [edit] into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should update your Firestore rules
try to change date for next  month or year

from :
request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 7, 4);

to :
request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 8, 4);

```html
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {

      allow read, write: if

          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 8, 4);

    }

  }

}
```