# Firebase : One Project , Multiple Database , Permission for databases besides default (Getting Permssion denied)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Firebase has added new feature, which allows for multiple databases.
I created a new database , say mynewdatabase. I configured googleservices.json for the flutter project

when i use :

```
firebasefirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(app: authrepo.app);
```

and then run a query , no exception is thrown , here firebase is getting connected to the default database

but when I use

```
firebasefirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(app: authrepo.app,databaseURL:"mynewdatabase");
```

I get exception:

> [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation

What permissions are required for the flutter end user to connect to the 2nd database, do i need to authenticate to it

I have not set any specific rules for second database and query is working for default database
From my understanding, it should follow rules what ever are set at default project level which is

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Solution :
As others have posted, its a rule issue . For multiple database , you have 2 define separate rules for the 2 databases , as given in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli , under section : Configuration for multiple Cloud Firestore databases

Comment: Have you set the proper rules for the second database?

Comment: Have a look at the suggestions in this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75179434/firebaseexception-cloud-firestore-permission-denied-the-caller-does-not-have) , [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66240201/the-caller-does-not-have-permission-to-execute-the-specified-operation) & [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71545794/dart-flutter-firebase-firebaseexception-cloud-firestore-permission-denied-the) which might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules you posted are **not** the default for a new database.

In my experience I can't access my non-default databases from client-side code until I deploy security rules to them with the gcloud CLI. Once I deploy the rules from my default database to the other one, I can access the database in the way you're doing.

So I recommend that you:

1. grab the rules from the default database of your project
2. deploy them to the non-default database through the gcloud CLI
3. re-run the code

Comment: How do you add rules to the non default database , there is no firebase console or firebase cli interface for it

Comment: You can deploy the rules through the `gcloud` CLI. I had already mentioned it in my running text, but now also added it to the steps

Comment: Thanks Frank , I am able to find a way (which is properly documented but i missed) to update rules : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli ; look at section - Configuration for multiple Cloud Firestore databases